# List(li) bullets does not align consistently across browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Here's the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/PZgn8/8/). Note that it looks different rendered in Chrome 27 and Firefox 21. I think it's a bug with Firefox, but Firefox gives me the outcome I want.

```
<ul style="text-align: center;">
    <li>
        <a href="#">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Two</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Two's child</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, for the child `ul` within the `li`, I need its list discs to be at the center too, not the side.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Provide [list-style-position:inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) to make it appear uniform across browsers, so that the bullet also gets the `text-align: center;` property.

```
li
{
    list-style-position:inside;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EZnEC/)

Comment: Nice answer (+1)..`Documentation`: http://dochub.io/#css/list-style-position and `Live example`: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/list-style/

Comment: @blunderboy Thanks. It is really wierd the way different browsers render the list eventhough default position is outside..

Comment: This is what made me read the documentation just to find if documentation says anything about browser specificity. Well it's always their choice how to play with rendering.

Comment: Thanks! 1 question though: exploring further, I found that `list-style-position: outside;` does NOT have an effect on how Firefox 21 renders the markup. http://jsfiddle.net/PZgn8/12/

Comment: @fterh That was the point; position: outside is the default value and is rendered differently (unpleasantly) in Chrome, IE 8,7 while FF , IE9 renders it as as if it is positioned inside.

Comment: Oh. I thought you meant different browsers have different default values for `list-style-position`.

Comment: This answer destroys the hanging indentation of lists. If you have list items that wrap to multiple lines, there is no good way to use `inside` and preserve the alignment of the text.